# Best practices for web service integration with sales force?

Tags: c#, .net, salesforce

I am looking to integrate with sales force, hence looking at different ways on their network of resources. I am looking to build this webservice on .Net platform. I am looking at simple fetch services. Best practices along with code samples are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [developerforce portal](http://developer.force.com/) is your best bet to get information and examples on using salesforce.com web services.  They have a ton of docs and examples.  Hard for me to pluck one out without knowing what you want to do, but it's a good resource.

Comment: i know this but how to work around it?? can i put my website custom data to salesforce objects. if yes then help me out.